# How to fetch an Item from DynamoDB and store the element to use it for Pytest?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, pytest, boto3

How to fetch an item from DynamoDB and use the environment(element) in Pytest? My function uses boto3 to get the Environment and which stores the environment in a list called `env[]`.

```
def get_environment():
    """
    Retrieves environment from DynamoDB
    :param ssm_client:
    :return:
    """
    env = []
    try:
        response = dynamodb_client.scan(
            TableName='accounts',
            AttributesToGet=['account_id','environment'],
            )
        env =  [ s['environment'] for s in response['Items'] ]
        return env
    except Exception as e:
        print("[ERROR] Failed")
```

Response:

```
[{'environment': {'S': 'sandbox'}, 'account_id': {'S': '409XX'}}, {'environment': {'S': 'services'}, 'account_id': {'S': '3228XX'}}, {'environment': {'S': 'non-production'}, 'account_id': {'S': '1145XX'}}, {'environment': {'S': 'production'}, 'account_id': {'S': '37988XX'}}, {'environment': {'S': 'non-production'}, 'account_id': {'S': '38856XXX'}}, {'environment': {'S': 'non-production'}, 'account_id': {'S': '10819XXXX'}}]
```

When I try to print the environment name, it throws an error

```
def print_environment():
    response = get_environment()
    environment =  [ item['environment'] for item in response ]
    print(environment)

  File "app.py", line 250, in print_environment
    environment =  [ item['environment'] for item in response ]
  File "app.py", line 250, in <listcomp>
    environment =  [ item['environment'] for item in response ]
KeyError: 'environment'
```

I want to fetch Environment only for the specific accountID and store it in `environment` and use it in pytest. Example

```
 def test_environment():
    environment = get_environment()
    account_id = get_account_ids()
    for accounts in account_id:     
        if (environment = 'production') then assert something .....
```

Comment: You are calling `get_accounts` instead of `get_environment`.

Comment: @hoefling It was a typo, I changed it still get the same error

Comment: @hoefling - This is related to the other question you were helping me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63436542/pytest-how-to-parameterize-tests-with-multiple-scenarios/63436665#63436665 . I need this environment name, so then I can write if (environment =='sandbox  ' ) then os.environ['environment'] = 'sandbox'`

Comment: As @balderman correctly points out, you are already returning the environment value of the response in `get_environment`. `item['environment']` thus will fail since `{'S': 'sandbox'}` doesn't contain the `environment` key anymore. Either `env = response['Items']` in `get_environment`, or `environment =  [item for item in response]` or just `environment = response` in `print_environment`.

Answer (score 2):

Your list of dicts does NOT contain 'environment' as a key.

It contains the values that were pointed by 'environment'.

Example for such a value is `{'S': 'sandbox'}, 'account_id': {'S': '409XX'}}`