# Pytest - How to Parameterize tests with multiple scenarios?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, amazon-dynamodb, pytest

I'm using pytest ,boto3 and aws and want to have dynamic assertions with parameterized tests. How to improve this code to only assert on a specific group of subnetids?

```
production_private_ids = ["subnet-08f6d70b65b5cxx38", "subnet-0b6aaaf1ce207xx03", "subnet-0e54fda8f811fxxd8"]) ....
nonproduction_private_ids = ["subnet-11f6xx0b65b5cxx38", "subnet-116aaaf1ce207xx99", "subnet-11xxfda8f811fxx77"]) ....


@pytest.mark.parametrize("subnet", ["production_private_ids", "nonproduction_private_ids", "nonproduction_public_ids","production_public_ids ")

# if environment = production, then only check if production_private_ids exists in team_subnet

def test_sharing_subnets_exist(subnet,accountid):
    team_subnet =  get_team_subnets(accountid)
    assert subnet in team_subnet


# if environment = nonproduction, then only check if nonproduction_private_ids exists in team_subnet
def test_sharing_subnets_exist(subnet,accountid):
    team_subnet =  get_team_subnets(accountid)
    assert subnet in team_subnet
```

Answer (score 0):

One common practice is to set and read from environment variables to determine which platform you are running from.

For example, in the environment you can have a variable `isProduction=1`. Then in your code, you can check by `os.environ['isProduction'] == 1`.

You can even save the private ids in the environment for reasons such as safety.
For example in the environment, you can have the following variables on nonproduction

```
id1="subnet-11f6xx0b65b5cxx38"
id2="subnet-116aaaf1ce207xx99"
id3"subnet-11xxfda8f811fxx77"
```

And another set on production machine

```
id1="subnet-08f6d70b65b5cxx38"
id2="subnet-0b6aaaf1ce207xx03"
id3="subnet-0e54fda8f811fxxd8"
```

in the code you do

```
import os
private_ids = [os.environ['id1'], os.environ['id2'], os.environ['id3']]
```

So you'll get the configs on each machine. Just make sure in your workflow/testflow the environment variables are correctly sourced.

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize the tests via metafunc if you need to execute additional logic on parametrization. Example:

```
import os
import pytest

production_private_ids = [...]
nonproduction_private_ids = [...]


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    # if the test has `subnet` in args, parametrize it now
    if 'subnet' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        # replace with your environment check
        if os.environ.get('NAME', None) == 'production':
            ids = production_private_ids
        else:
            ids = nonproduction_private_ids
        metafunc.parametrize('subnet', ids)


def test_sharing_subnets_exist(subnet, accountid):
    team_subnet =  get_team_subnets(accountid)
    assert subnet in team_subnet
```

Now running `pytest ...` will check only non-production IDs, while `NAME="production" pytest ...` will check only production IDs.

Comment: Thanks,  I actually query dynamodb to check for `environment_name` in the account table . Maybe I can write if (environment =='sandbox  ' ) then os.environ['environment'] = 'sandbox'`

Comment: You can replace it with any check you find suitable, e.g. `if get_environment() contains smth: ...` Look at your code to find a suitable check.